# Customize JSON output from C# Web Service

Tags: c#, json, web-services

I have the following output from a C# web service:

```
{"CallResult":[{"CompanyId":"AAA900134-904","CompanyName":"MID"}]}
```

I want the output to only contain an array of JSON like the following:

```
[{"CompanyId":"AAA900134-904","CompanyName":"MID"}]
```

I'm not sure how to customize the output.  Do I have to return a string and customize the JSON manually or is there another way?  Thanks.

Comment: Show us the code of the data model returned by your API

Comment: What is server implemented using? Web API? WCF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution.

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "/CallResult/{username}/{company}")]
    CallResult_Result[] CallResult(string username, string company);
```

I had to change

```
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped
```

to

```
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, such as actual data example (this json refers to 1 object only), here is what I can suggest:

Create 2 custom classes as follows:

```
public class CallResultClass
{
    public List<InnerClass> CallResult { get; set; }
}

public class InnerClass
{
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

Then, along with `using System.Web.Script.Serialization;`, you can deserialize the json as follows:

```
string json = "{\"CallResult\":[{\"CompanyId\":\"AAA900134-904\",\"CompanyName\":\"MID\"}]}";

JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var callres = (CallResultClass)js.Deserialize(json, typeof(CallResultClass));

var companyInfo = callres.CallResult;
```

If your json contains a list of CallResults, a simple modification to the code can accommodate for that. There is no scenario where modifying the json string would be viable (there is always a clean way).

For reference & examples read [JavaScriptSerializer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples).